# Redacting post to hide device serial number

Tags: discussion

It appears that new (as well as some old) users on Ask Different do not blur out/hide the device serial number when posting screenshot as part of their question.

While some may argue if sharing device serial number publicly is/is not harmful, this act is generally accidental on authors part due to ignorance.

What should be the recommended approach in such cases?

- Should other users/moderatos proactively edit the post to hide the serial number?
- Should the original author be notified about the visible serial number and be requested to take corrective measure(s)? (Deleting and re-posting for e.g.)
- Should the moderators be flagged to remove the serial number from the edit history?

Additionally

- Should serial numbers be redacted?
- What harm does it cause to leave serial number in visible text?

Kindly share your thought(s) so that a standardized approach can be formulated to handle such cases.

Comment: thanks!  Want me to ask a simply yes no as well. Is posting a serial number harmful or “ list the harm this causes”  - I’m curious what you see as the harm in leaving that up.

Comment: Note that a simple edit will not remove the number as old version of the post are still readable. I think mods only can really do a redaction

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for raising this. I've also noticed the same thing, but don't find it to be a concern.

You've asked a few questions, so I'll provide my brief views below:

> Should other users/moderatos proactively edit the post to hide the
>   serial number?

No.

> Should the original author be notified about the visible serial number
>   and be requested to take corrective measure(s)? (Deleting and
>   re-posting for e.g.)

No. I don't think we should be telling them to take corrective action for something that in reality poses very little (practically no) risk. I guess I could see an argument (maybe/maybe not) for letting the OP know their serial number is visible in case they weren't aware, and that should they have a particular concern with the idea of their serial number being visible, explain that they can choose to edit their post.

> Should the moderators be flagged to remove the serial number from the
>   edit history?

By users generally, no. By the original author? Yes, but only if they're concerned about it, no need otherwise.

> Should serial numbers be redacted?

No, unless the original author has requested a redaction.

> What harm does it cause to leave serial number in visible text?

I think this should be dealt with as a separate question as it's potentially opinion-based and could invite lots of views/answers. I also don't think it should be worded as *"What harm **does** it cause"*, but rather *"What harm **could** it cause"*. [I think bmike is going to post a separate question on this].

Without going into details here, my answer would be to say that there's essentially no harm, but in an absolute worst case scenario there are a couple of *possible* ways someone could try to use a serial number (but not in a way that causes harm to the original author). In fact, the only circumstances I can envisage a serial number being manipulated in a way that could cause harm to the original author involves someone who is both familiar with some of Apple's internal processes **and** also has access to personal details about the original author. An extremely low risk in the context of our site.

Comment: It's also possible for a serial number to cause harm if someone knew a person in real life *and* knew the serial number of their device. This would allow them to make a connection between a person's real life and online personas... but honestly, that's something for the author to think about, not us.

Comment: @Undo Yep, I guess that's a possibility. It's another example of my point that a person really has to have *access to personal details about the original author* to cause what I would call *harm*. But of course, what causes 'harm' is highly subjective. Regardless, you're right - it's something for the author to think about. As far as I can tell, at most we *may* consider pointing out that a screenshot displays a serial number on the off chance they're not aware. It's up to them then if they want to take some action.